# Using a recursive function to find the factorial of a given integer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a recursive function to print the factorial of a given integer. Ask the user to enter a positive integer and then display the output on a page. For example, if the user enters 5, the output must be

5 × 4 × 3 × 2 × 1 = 120

```js
var integer = prompt("Enter a positive integer.");
function factorialize(num) {
    if(num == 0 || num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return num + " x " + factorialize(num-1) + num * factorialize(num-1);
    }
}
document.write(factorialize(integer));
```

Comment: `factorialize(num-1)` returns either `1` (for `num === 2`) or a string. `num * factorialize(num-1)` is either `2` or `NaN`.

Comment: I don't think you can (easily) use the same function to create the string and also calculate the multiplication result.

Comment: What's the expected result with `0!`, `0 = 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `runningTotal` of the sum so far to each recursive call. You can also keep the solution compact using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
function factorialize(n, runningTotal = 1) {
  if (n === 1) return `1 = ${runningTotal}`;
  return `${n} x ${factorialize(n - 1, runningTotal * n)}`;
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think make that recursively is quite confused:

```js
function factorialize(n, expression = '', result = 0) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return null
  } else if (n === 0) {
    return (expression || n) + " = " + result
  }

  const newExpression = result ? expression + " x " + n : n
  const newResult = !result ? n : result * n

  return factorialize(n - 1, newExpression, newResult)
}

console.log(factorialize(5))
```

Is better to segregate the responsibilities:

```js
function factorial(n) {
  let fact = 1

  if (n < 0) {
    console.warn("Error");
    return 0
  } else {
    for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
      fact = fact * i;
    }
  }

  return fact
}

function factorialExpression(n) {
  let expression = ""

  if (n < 0) {
    console.warn("Error");
    return ""
  } else {
    for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
      expression += (i < n ? " x " : "") + i
    }
  }

  return expression
}

function factorialize(n) {
  if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
    return n + " = " + n
  } else if (n > 1) {
    return factorialExpression(n) + " = " + factorial(n)
  }

  return null
}

console.log(factorialize(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handover the parts of product and result.

```js
function factorialize(num, product = 1, result = '') {
    return num === 0 || num === 1
        ? result + (result && ' x ') + num + ' -> ' + product
        : factorialize(num - 1, product * num, result + (result && ' x ') + num);
}

console.log(factorialize(5));
console.log(factorialize(2));
console.log(factorialize(1));
console.log(factorialize(0));
```